# Arch linux (grub) not booting

Tags: boot, grub

I installed Arch Linux using `chroot` from USB and removed Windows 11 completely. No errors occurred while installing, but after choosing Arch Linux to boot, when entering correct password it does not boot and shows:

```
Loading linux linux,
Loading initial ramdisk.
```

And then returns again to login page. I tried removing quiet, but it didn't work. Windows manager installed is sway and only 512 GB SSD single drive is entirely allocated for Arch.

Please help by telling steps to solve this, I can't find anything working over the internet

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have two Questions. First, does you user have a Homefolder? And do you have a Desktop Enviroment or a Window Manager?

Comment: Press Ctrl-Alt-F2 and try to login as root.

Comment: Yes there is a home folder and sway is the wm

Comment: After my experiencs, something is missing. Some drivers like a X-Server, as example. So far, i didn't use the install script from Arch, so I dont know, what the Script is bringing with. Maby, can you tell, what packets you have installed for you grafical enviroment?

Comment: Are you showing the images in order? Are you saying that after booting into Arch and getting to the login page, attempting to log in actually ***reboots*** your computer and takes you back to the grub menu (the second image you show)?